# Hybris Server showing Garbage collection issue?

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection, wrapper, sap-commerce-cloud

I had recently installed java adopt JDK 1.8.0_202 version.

It worked fine for the first time and later when i start hybris server getting the below issue again & again on console :

```
JVMJ9GC063E Unable to open file '/opt/hybris/log/tomcat/java_gc_ger-d-maa-apsp-001.log' for writing
```

```
<allocation-stats totalBytes="223210880" >
  <allocated-bytes non-tlh="13688" tlh="223197192" />
  <largest-consumer threadName="localhost-startStop-1" threadId="0000000002F7B000" bytes="217285784" />
</allocation-stats>
<gc-op id="2563" type="scavenge" timems="53.990" contextid="2560" timestamp="2019-03-14T15:18:57.791">
  <scavenger-info tenureage="14" tenuremask="4000" tiltratio="88" />
  <memory-copied type="nursery" objects="394430" bytes="16048744" bytesdiscarded="115760" />
  <finalization candidates="204" enqueued="174" />
  <ownableSynchronizers candidates="3195" cleared="7" />
  <references type="soft" candidates="9645" cleared="0" enqueued="0" dynamicThreshold="32" maxThreshold="32" />
  <references type="weak" candidates="6673" cleared="84" enqueued="67" />
</gc-op>
<gc-end id="2564" type="scavenge" contextid="2560" durationms="54.398" usertimems="46.801" systemtimems="0.000" timestamp="2019-03-14T15:18:57.791" activeThreads="2">
  <mem-info id="2565" free="564246568" total="1073741824" percent="52">
    <mem type="nursery" free="224266520" total="268435456" percent="83">
      <mem type="allocate" free="224266520" total="240451584" percent="93" />
      <mem type="survivor" free="0" total="27983872" percent="0" />
    </mem>
    <mem type="tenure" free="339980048" total="805306368" percent="42" macro-fragmented="3110739">
      <mem type="soa" free="299715344" total="765041664" percent="39" />
      <mem type="loa" free="40264704" total="40264704" percent="100" />
    </mem>
    <pending-finalizers system="174" default="0" reference="67" classloader="0" />
    <remembered-set count="33247" />
  </mem-info>
</gc-end>
<cycle-end id="2566" type="scavenge" contextid="2560" timestamp="2019-03-14T15:18:57.792" />
<allocation-satisfied id="2567" threadId="0000000002F7B000" bytesRequested="48" />
<af-end id="2568" timestamp="2019-03-14T15:18:57.792" threadId="0000000002F7B988" success="true" from="nursery"/>
<exclusive-end id="2569" timestamp="2019-03-14T15:18:57.792" durationms="55.438" />

<exclusive-start id="2570" timestamp="2019-03-14T15:19:06.478" intervalms="8740.918">
  <response-info timems="0.039" idlems="0.039" threads="0" lastid="0000000002F7B000" lastname="localhost-startStop-1" />
</exclusive-start>
<af-start id="2571" threadId="0000000002F7B988" totalBytesRequested="24" timestamp="2019-03-14T15:19:06.478" intervalms="8740.939" type="nursery" />
<cycle-start id="2572" type="scavenge" contextid="0" timestamp="2019-03-14T15:19:06.478" intervalms="8740.941" />
<gc-start id="2573" type="scavenge" contextid="2572" timestamp="2019-03-14T15:19:06.479">
  <mem-info id="2574" free="339975744" total="1073741824" percent="31">
    <mem type="nursery" free="0" total="268435456" percent="0">
      <mem type="allocate" free="0" total="240451584" percent="0" />
      <mem type="survivor" free="0" total="27983872" percent="0" />
    </mem>
    <mem type="tenure" free="339975744" total="805306368" percent="42">
      <mem type="soa" free="299711040" total="765041664" percent="39" />
      <mem type="loa" free="40264704" total="40264704" percent="100" />
    </mem>
    <remembered-set count="34712" />
  </mem-info>
</gc-start>
```

Any help would be appreciated?
Thanks,
Mohammed

Comment: What is the issue? You don't want this logs in console?

Comment: @talex  Yes i dont want to see this again & again in console...Is it possible to stop that?

Answer (score 0):

This logs produced by `-verbose:gc` (or similar) JVM option.

You should remove that option if you don't need this logs.

Comment: Can i pls know what is the location of this from where i need to remove?

Comment: How you start your app?

Comment: i can see -verbose:gc this in wrapper.conf file....can i comment it for changes to get refelcted?  i startmy server from console hybrisserver.bat command

Comment: Yes. Remove it and restart your app.

Comment: Even after removing.. i can still see them on console

Comment: Check your local.properties file for tomcat.generaloptions and tomcat.debugjavaoptions configuration params. wrapper.conf file overwriting with clean build.

Comment: @mkysoft You want me to remove that from generaloptions?

Comment: In Hybris `verbose:gc` option is usually added in the environment variable `CATALINA_OPTS` and sometimes in `JAVA_OPTS`, albeit you can add it to the configuration of any *environment variable*.